# explode list and get index values for each list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- original DataFrame `df`

  ```
    label  value
  0     a      1
  1     a      2
  2     b      3
  3     a      4
  4     b      5
  ```
- `ds = df.groupby('label')['value'].apply(list)`

  ```
  label
  a    [1, 2, 4]
  b       [3, 5]
  ```
- `ds.explode()` generate

  ```
    label
    a    1
    a    2
    a    4
    b    3
    b    5
  ```

What I need is a new column to represents the position of the item in the `value` column in the original list.

```
 label value position
 a    1      0
 a    2      1
 a    4      2
 b    3      0
 b    5      1
```

---

**update:**

Example above is not appropriate, suppose the original dataframe is

```
  label   value
0     a  [1, 2]
1     a     [2]
2     b     [3]
3     a     [4]
4     b     [5]
```

`df.explode('value')` gives

```
  label value
0     a     1
0     a     2
1     a     2
2     b     3
3     a     4
4     b     5
```

how I get

```
  label value position
0     a     1  0
0     a     2  1
1     a     2  0
2     b     3  0
3     a     4  0
4     b     5  0
```

Comment: `df['position'] = df.groupby('label').cumcount()`

Comment: BTW, do you really need explode? How about just `df.sort_values("label")`?

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks and no, I've edited my question

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Got it retracted close vote ;)

Comment: @Chris my intention is to expand the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get length of list in `value` then apply [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-range) on it using [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). Now, explode `value`

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.len().map(np.arange)
#                                 _.map(range) # Alternative
df.explode('value')

  label value
0     a     0
0     a     1
1     a     0
2     b     0
3     a     0
4     b     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try:

```
 df['position']=df.groupby(['label'])['value'].cumcount()
```